# LinqtoExcel trouble reading Dates

Tags: c#, csv, date, linq-to-excel

I have a CSV where one of two of the columns are dates, "Due Date" and "Review Date" and both have the format `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm`

In my row to use for LinqToExcel these two columns are:

```
[ExcelColumn("Due Date")]
public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }

[ExcelColumn("Review Date")]
public DateTime ReviewDate { get; set; }
```

Main problem is these are MinValue despite all rows in the CSV having a value. I thought maybe it's to do with how it parses the date, so even importing it as a string it come through as null.

I've encountered this problem before and in the past I've just renamed the column... don't know why it solved it but it did, but this time I'm stumped. I can't get it to read the date at all.

How do I get it to read in the date?

Current code to read it in

```
var csv = new ExcelQueryFactory(folderPath);
var addressSheet = csv.Worksheet<AddressDto>();
var data = addressSheet.ToList();
```

I don't need to specify a sheet name for a CSV file.

Comment: Can you please post the code where you are retrieving the dates?

Comment: Saving the CSV file as an Excel file seems to have solved it, but it doesn't explain why this has happened.

Comment: I hadn't refreshed so I'd not seen your comment. I'll edit the post

Comment: I've edited the post